# How to Change background colors on only one page on Squarespace Henson template?

Tags: background, squarespace

I try everything on this and other forum to do it and not ask people..
But nothing happened! haha

I would like to know if someone here know how to change the background colors on Henson template on Squarespace ? (So also all the texte of the page).

I try this in the CSS section but it didn't worked.

```
   #collection-5e827250f835166c09c3dcbe 
   {background-image:url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c3a93e22487fd34bb34eaa9/t/5ea1dd8bda93e023950c5bcf/1587666340724/Background.jpg"); 
   background-size:cover;  
   background-position:center; 
   }
```

And i try this in the injection code :

```
<style>
#collection-5e827250f835166c09c3dcbe {
background-color:#000; 
}
</style>
```

Thank you in advance,
hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Henson template has a "title-card-overlay" that, if enabled, makes it non-obvious to change the initial background color of a the page.

To change the background color of a specific page, add the following CSS via the CSS Editor/Custom CSS:

```
#collection-57ae1156e3df28c4ce90ea48 .main-content {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#collection-57ae1156e3df28c4ce90ea48 .title-card-overlay {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Of course, in the above code, change the collection ID `57ae1156e3df28c4ce90ea48` to the ID of the page in question.

Comment: Wow, it works directly haha i just spend all my day trying to do it..

Thanks Brandon!

By the way, do you know how i can put every text in white, (to invert everything) ?

Nav, title, logos img and texte ?

Let me know, (Thanks so much!)